# Why would the Amazon Mechanical Turk Web Interface be out of sync with the API?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I've been using the [rturk](https://github.com/mdp/rturk) Ruby library to call the Amazon Mechanical Turk API. I'm doing basic things like approving and rejecting. After doing so successfully, I am now looking over the (a) AMT Web UI and (b) an exported CSV.  Neither shows the approvals or rejections I just made.

What is going on?

I would not expect a time lag. How can I get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from James@AWS over at the Mechanical Turk forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=398300

> Please see the last response in this thread:
>
> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=175067&#175067
>
> The short answer is that the web interface doesn't see updates from certain actions taken in the API. This is a known limitation.

From where I sit, this "known limitation" would be better described as a bug.

Comment: 4 years later and this issue is still present. How annoying.

Comment: 4 more years and it's still present